# trouble save the image upload in php

Tags: javascript, image, button, upload

i have this master page and a web form with the master page the problem i have is that the code wont run or save into the folder i want it to, so how do i change the code in the vb?
 basically i have a javascript which have a input that allow me to upload a file or image, but the problem, it seem like total skip the code inside

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
            var counter = 0;

            function AddFileUpload() {
                var div = document.createElement('DIV');
                div.innerHTML = '<input id="file' + counter + '" name = "file' + counter + '" type="file" /><input id="Button' + counter + '" type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveFileUpload(this)" />';
                document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").appendChild(div);
                counter++;
            }
            function RemoveFileUpload(div) {
                document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
            }
            $(document).ready(function () {
                AddFileUpload();
            });

        </script>  


<span style ="font-family:Arial">Click to add files</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <br /><br />
        <div id = "FileUploadContainer">
            <!--FileUpload Controls will be added here -->
        </div>
        <br />
        <input id="ButtonAdd" type="button" value="add" onclick = "AddFileUpload()" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload"  />
    <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
        <br />

     Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
            For i As Integer = 0 To Request.Files.Count - 1
                Dim PostedFile As HttpPostedFile = Request.Files(i)
                If PostedFile.ContentLength > 0 Then
                    Dim FileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(PostedFile.FileName)
                    PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Files\img\") + FileName)

                Else
                    lbl2.Text = "No images have been selected to upload "
                End If
            Next
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing.. But by the things that i have understood from your question. i would say if u have problem of adding forms into your content form u can remove form from the master page and then u have to add forms to each content form you will add.

Bu if you want multiple forms in your page u can do so by making only one form visible at a time.

But see to it that the form is in another placeholder from the one which already had form in it.
Question is a bit confusing but hope i was able to give u solution ...

Comment: there no error, i update my code, basically i have a javascript which have a input that allow me to upload a file or image, but the problem, it seem like total skip the code inside

Comment: Yes got your Problem. It seems like the JavaScript code creates the control on fly and is not adding it to the actual code (check in view source). Thus asp.net is not getting any thing to upload.

Comment: so can you show me how, i have put in the view source below the javascript code, i not sure how to solve this, please help

Comment: the only solution that i can think of, for time being , is to make the div `runat=server` and the from code-behind assign it's `InnerHtml`. But this would cause post Back.

Comment: But make sure that when you add buttons or controls dynamically, add it during `init` function of page. Otherwise you won't be able to access or fire the events of that control.

Comment: it will be much easier for me to understand

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7312/discussion-between-actking-and-rohitwagh)