# javascript to calculate total price?

Tags: javascript, gridview

I have a textbox and 2 labels, one of the labels is 'price' and another is 'total price', they are in one of the columns in a gridview.

The gridview is bound to a database table called Product, basically it will show a list of products and i need the javascript to calculate the total price by taking price * quantity.

I tried the below code, but when i enter a value in the textbox, the label for total price changes, but it affects every row, which is not what i want. How should I change it?

```
 $("[id*=txtQuantity]").live("change", function () {
               if (isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
                   $(this).val('0');
               } else {
                   $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()).toString());
               }
           }).trigger("change");

           $("[id*=txtQuantity]").live("keyup", function () {
               if (!jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                   if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
                       var row = $(this).closest("table");
                       $("[id*=lblTotalCost]", row).html(parseFloat($("[id*=price]", row).html()) * parseFloat($(this).val()));
                   }
               } else {
                   $(this).val('');
               }

           }).trigger("keyup");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the markup it's hard to say exactly, but if you say it changes the price ok, but just affects too many rows, i'd take a look at the selector you use around here:

```
var row = $(this).closest("table");
$("[id*=lblTotalCost]", row).html(parseFloat($("[id*=price]", row).html()) * parseFloat($(this).val()));
```

The `row` variable is an entire table, and you are then finding anything where the ID contains `lblTotalCost`, it looks like this is returning all the total cost fields in the table, and setting them all at once.

Again without seeing the markup it's hard to advise, but possibly try changing:

```
$(this).closest("table");
```

to:

```
$(this).closest("tr");
```

to limit the scope of the code after it.

Comment: thanks beside this can you also help me see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125460/urgent-help-need-trouble-save-the-image-uploadc
i cant solve it, it is urgent for me